# method, that accesses a conditional class member, does not compile only when being invoked

Tags: c++, templates, dependent-name

i wrote the following class that has a conditional member `_s` and `worksOnlyForString` method that accesses the member as `std::string`. if `worksOnlyForString` method is not invoked the code compiles even if the member is not `std::string`.

there is a well-known c++ rule - a template function is fully compiled only when being used. But in my case, the conditional member triggers this behavior.

The question is - why the code compiles.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>

template<bool isString>
struct S
{
    void worksAlways()
    {
        std::cout << _s;
    }

    // compiles for isString == false. (if not used)
    // but why
    void worksOnlyForString()
    {
        std::cout<<_s.size();
    }


    std::conditional_t<isString, std::string, int> _s;
#if 0 
    //this part does not compile and it is expected and ok
    void checkUnconditionalMember()
    {
        std::cout<<_i.size();
    }
    int _i;
#endif    
};

int main()
{
    S<true> s;
    s._s = "xxx";
    s.worksOnlyForString(); // ok prints "3"

    S<false> s1; // why does this line compile ?
    s1._s = 99;
    s1.worksAlways(); // ok prints "99"

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand your question: you're observing exactly the behaviour you describe, namely that template member functions are only instantiated when used.

Comment: As you say, it is "fully compiled only when being used". Why are you expecting a compilation error when you're not using `S<false>::worksOnlyForString` anywhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code is not name dependant, so compiler spot error.

```
void checkUnconditionalMember()
{
    std::cout<<_i.size();
}
```

In

```
std::conditional_t<isString, std::string, int> _s;

void worksOnlyForString()
{
    std::cout << _s.size();
}
```

- `_s` is name dependent (depends of `isString`).
- and so for `std::cout << _s.size();`.

So full check is only done when the function is instantiated.

Instantiating the class doesn't instantiate each method.